# How do you say the language of instruction is in Japanese or if something is taught in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese

There is a Japanese school in a foreign country. I want to ask if this school's main language is Japanese, if the language of instruction is Japanese?

How do I ask this? I know the term, teach (oshie) and learn (manabu), but is there a more specific term when used in this context?

If I were to ask 'At the school, is the instruction in Japanese?'.

UPDATE:

The word I was looking for was 習（なら）っていますか？

See accepted answer for an alternative phrase, and see follow-up comments for the full phrase using 習（なら）っていますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "**そちらでは授業【じゅぎょう】は日本語【にほんご】で行【おこな】っていますか？**", abbreviating the grammar since if I start to explain the grammar I think I just will end up in purely confusing you more. In English, your "'At the school, is the instruction in Japanese?'" will be the translation....

By the way, from my personal experience, most of the Japanese ( teaching ) school has at least one person who can speak English, I personally would like to suggest for you to try to ask in English. Otherwise, if you ask in Japanese so fluently there would be the possibility they would reply in Japanese and you would not be able to understand the reply....

Have a nice day.

Comment: The last part 行っていますか. Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: The alternative? ummmm..probably **そちらでは先生（せんせい）は日本語（にほんご）を日本語（にほんご）で教（おし）えていますか**?? Perhaps?? In English, it would be translated as "At your school, do teachers teach Japanese in Japanese?". ?

Comment: I found the word I was looking for. 'Naratte imasuka'.

Comment: Uh, then how about "生徒（せいと）は日本語（にほんご）で習（なら）っていますか？” In English "Are students taught in Japanese?"

Comment: @Void I feel 教える is much better than 習う in this situation. I'd imagine they're learning something other than Japanese when you say 日本語で習う.